# Can we add only BaseActivity in ActivityBuilder module as '@ContributesAndroidInjector' instead of mentioning every 'Activity'?

Tags: android, dagger-2

In my application, I am using dagger-2 for Android,
I am extending my every activity with `BaseActivity` which extends `DaggerAppCompatActivity`.
I have created a 'module' (`ActivityBuilder`) where we are suppose to specify every new activity as `@ContributesAndroidInjector`.

Can we specify only `BaseActivity` instead of mentionting every activity as `BaseActivity` is parent for all activities?